# Vuetify: maximize video size in Carousel Slide

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm working with Vuejs and Nuxt and would like to display a video in a vuetify carousel component :

This can be seen here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqBEqb

This is working size but I want ro resize the video to fill the carousel slide. I've tried:

```
<iframe width="auto" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zjcVPZCG4sM" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
```

and

```
<iframe width="max" height="max" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zjcVPZCG4sM" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
```

But there is no change. How can I maximize the video size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `max` value for width or height attributes: the closest thing is using `100%`. However, using `height: 100%` will not work: the reason is because it has to be relative to a certain value.

Vuetify's carousel [has a default height of `500px`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/carousels), so if you set your `<iframe>` element to have a width of 100% and a height of 500px, that should fix the issue, e.g.:

```
#app iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

See updated Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VOegwN

---

If you want to future-proof your setup (i.e. to protect yourself against future changes in the default carousel height), you should then set the height explicitly:

```
<v-carousel v-bind:height="500">
```

Comment: Will there be a problem with responsive displays if you hard code in a height of 500 px?

Comment: @user61629 Yes and no. Yes if you forget the update the height in both places. No if you remember :)